# Regarding product list API to get only list of product for one store via REST API Magento2

Tags: magento2

[Domain]/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=eq

I have used this to get all products whose status is enabled.
Can we pass store id to get all products for particular store?